# how do i take each value from date in jsp

Tags: sql, string, jsp

I have this in my form

```
<form action="newjsp.jsp">
    <input name="date" type="date" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this in my newjsp.jsp

```
<%
String Month = (String)request.getParameter("date").substring(0, 2);
String Day = (String)request.getParameter("date").substring(3, 5);
String Year = (String)request.getParameter("date").substring(6, 10);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Database","Administrator","admin");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ADMINISTRATOR.DATA(Year, Month, Day) values ('" + Year + "','" + Month + "','" + Day + "'");
if (i > 0) {
    response.sendRedirect("registerm.jsp");
}
%>
```

What I want is to take day, month and year from the date input and store each in a column in my database.
What am I doing wrong? or how is it done?

Comment: *what am I doing wrong?*: the error message you get (if any) should tell you that. What happens? That said, you're doing several things wrong: not using prepared statements, using scriptlets in JSPs instead of using controllers written in Java, opening a new connection at each request, not respecting Java naming conventions, not validating your inputs, etc.

Comment: This is what i am geting: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 67.

Comment: Print your SQL query, and you'll find out. Hint: you forgot a parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet, i really didn't notice. Works now.